# Good complete backup solution?

Tags: backup

I recently had a problem with my phone where I was forced to do a factory reset and lost a bunch of stuff.

To prevent that happening again I want a complete solution that reliably backs up my device at specified intervals. The desired result being the ability to restore my "environment" to a fresh phone if needed.

What solutions have worked for people in the past? I have tried Titanium Backup but that seems to require root and I don't want to root my device.

Note: Please do not consider the native backup solution provided by Google in Android (That failed me).

Many thanks
Conor

Comment: Depending on the manufacturer, some offer their own backup solution that works better than Google's one (which doesn't seem to notify me that it restored any data when reinstalling an app). Otherwise look at the related questions and their solutions like `adb backup` and others. [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices?rq=1)

Comment: Sadly, from my experience, you cannot do this properly without a rooted phone. And I am suffering from this now. I miss my rooted phone. The Storage Access Framework nonsense is just killing my ability to work with external storage in a free and functional way. :(

Answer (score 0):

I usually just export my contacts and my internal storage. For more you might use the shell (and where you can choose your preferred file explorer) and copy the files you need to your desktop/laptop pc/external SD card. (app data for example needs to be copied with adb, so you have to use the shell) If you have some apps you can not reinstall, for example if they are not on the playstore anymore, then you can use an apk extractor, I prefer the one from F-droid. If you want to make a custom recover like backup you might want to look up how twrp does it.

Comment: What do you mean by *export* [cut] *my internal storage*? Sure, the contact part is easy but the rest?